# Semantic UI two almost-identical dropdowns - one works, one does not

Tags: jquery, node.js, semantic-ui

I'm building a system that requires two dropdown on the same screen, literally one under another.

The below is an exact representation of my code.

```
<div class="field">
    <label>Operational Category</label>
    <div class="ui selection dropdown">
        <input type="hidden" class="ui hidden timeType" name="time_type" value="10" />
        <i class="simple dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="menu">
            <% for (let thisTimeType of timeTypes) { %>
                <div data-value="<%= thisTimeType.getId() %>"><%= thisTimeType.getName() %></div>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label>Task Category</label>
    <div class="ui selection dropdown">
        <input type="hidden" class="ui hidden category" name="card_category_id" value="<%= card_category_id %>" />
        <i class="simple dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">(no category)</div>
        <div class="menu">
            <% for (let thisCardCategory of cardCategories) { %>
            <% let isActive  = (thisCardCategory.getId() == card_category_id) ? 'active item' : 'item' %>
                <div class="<%= isActive %>" data-value="<%= thisCardCategory.getId() %>"><%= thisCardCategory.getName() %></div>
            <% } %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the bottom of the file is a call to

```
jQuery('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

One of the dropdowns (ironically, the second one) works and the other one does not and I cannot figure out why. Things I've tried:

- Giving the first one a 'default text'
- Removing the second one to see if the first one will work
- using 'simple' class to see if it's constructed okay. It hovers and shows options, although it looks rubbish.

Any thoughts? because I'm thoroughly confused by this. Am I missing something super-obvious?

Comment: You're missing the `item` css className (`class="item"`) on the first dropdown. It shold've been something like: `<div class="item" data-value="<%= thisTimeType.getId() %>"><%= thisTimeType.getName() %></div>`

Comment: *facepalm* That was it. So obvious when I look at it now! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: As per IronGeek's comment, the answer is super-simple:

I was missing the `item` css className (class="item") on the first dropdown.

For example: `<div class="item" data-value="<%= thisTimeType.getId() %>"><%= thisTimeType.getName() %></div>`